# ajax url path not working no clue

Tags: ajax

my ajax check data is local on folder class / classvalidation.php. if i copy the file and paste it out with my file and change

```
url:'classvalidation.php',
```

then it work, what cant i make it class/classvalidation.php work ?

```
$.ajax({  
          type:"POST",  
          url:'class/classvalidation.php',
          async:false,
          data:{'username':username_value},  
          success: function(data){  
          var usernameAvailable = JSON.parse(data);
          var color = usernameAvailable.exists ? '#dfe0e6' : 'red';
            $("#user-result").html(usernameAvailable.message);
            $('#user-result').css('color', color);
            $("#reg-username").css('border-color', color);
            if(usernameAvailable.exists === true){
                userpass = true;
            }else{
                userpass = false;
            }
          }
        });
```